# change whatsapp url dependig on screen size

Tags: whatsapp, jscript

My website is [http://www.silvertreeestates.co.za/]

I have a Whatsapp button on each property and from a mobile phone the link works because I'm using api.whatsapp.com, however if you are using on a Laptop this link does not work as the url needed is then web.whatsapp.com

So wondering if any of you smart people can suggest an alternative, or script I could use to automatically select the correct url to obtain the result on both phone and PC ??

[http://www.silvertreeestates.co.za/#P107239544] Example

```
<!--Property Listing Start-->
```

click image to view gallery

### This is a stunning, spacious duplex, facebrick unit in a popular complex, close to amenities.

Enjoy this sunny and bright home which offers a spacious open plan dining and lounge area with laminated floors, chandeliers and immediate access into the private garden. Downstairs guest toilet. Open plan modern kitchen with gas stove and scullery. Upstairs has three spacious bedrooms all leading onto the balcony and two neat bathrooms. Double garage. Privacy and close to Private Schools and Shopping Centres...

## Poortview

#### R 1,595,000

232½2YY

180m²TBAR 2,251

Can you afford this mortgage (based on 20 Years @ Prime) per month - R 15,657

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen.width` in JavaScript if you want to determine the current screen width.

Or,

```
if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // mobile!
}
```

should help in choosing between mobile/PC.

Comment: ok, and the script to change the url??? sorry my jscript skill are limited so please be patient with me

Comment: You have a simple if...else.. condition with the changes URLs